# Firebase OAuth doesn't work on Safari with onAuthStateChanged

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, oauth, safari

I've got an issue that seems to be very specific to Safari with Firebase OAuth (it works in Chrome and Firefox as expected).

I'm implementing Firebase Authentication using the `signInWithRedirect` method and have tried Option 1 from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices, and spent a long time researching but cannot find a solution. The closest thread is this: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6716, but none of the solutions work for me.

I've reduced the code to the snippet below which works on Chrome but doesn't log the user in when using Safari.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  User,
  signInWithRedirect,
  signOut,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { connectAuthEmulator, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { connectFirestoreEmulator, getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.ENV_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.ENV_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.ENV_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.ENV_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.ENV_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.ENV_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.ENV_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);

connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099');
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080);

const AppCore: React.FC = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  const signInGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  };

  const logOut = (): Promise<void> => signOut(auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubsrcibe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      console.log('auth changed', user);
      setUser(user);
    });
    return unsubsrcibe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {!user ? (
        <button onClick={() => signInGoogle()}>Sign In Google</button>
      ) : (
        <div>
          Logged In!
          <button onClick={async () => await logOut()}>Logout</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default AppCore;
```

If I preserve console logs during the OAuth flow in Safari, the only error is related to the websocket connection (the error doesn't appear in Chrome or Firefox).
[image]

Has anyone experienced anything similar?